# VueJS make instance property reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-reactivity

I am building a VueJS plugin using [instance properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html) and i need to bring back some reactive values back to VueJS.

**My searches :**

I dont understand the stuff behind `Object.defineProperty()`, i searched for [vuex getters initialisation](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/src/store.js#L235) as my logic is similar but i dont understand how operate properly.

**Simple Example :**

Below a VueJS snippet attached to his prototype, `main.js` :

```
Vue.prototype.$ajax = {
  loading: false,
  isLoading () {
    return this.loading
  }
}
```

Now, accessing it from a component, `component.vue` :

```
export default {
    computed: {
      loading () {
        return this.$ajax.isLoading()
      }
    },
    created () {
      let self = this

      setInterval(() => {
        console.log(this.loading, this.$ajax.isLoading())
      }, 100)

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.$ajax.loading = true
      }, 1000)
    }
  }
}
```

**Example result :**

Before `setTimeout` we have `false false` (this is the expected output), but after `setTimeout` we have `false true` (the getter does not receive the modification, but the direct accesor has the value).

Any idea for bringing some reactivity stuff into my `$ajax.isLoading()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, by digging `vuex` code i found a solution : use a Vue instance inside the plugin with your data into in order to bring reactivity outside.

From the question :

```
Vue.prototype.$ajax = {
  _vm: new Vue({data: {
    loading: false
  }}),
  setLoading (loading) {
    this._vm.$data.loading = loading
  },
  isLoading () {
    return this._vm.$data.loading
  }
}
```

And i just changed the direct accessor by this setter on my component :

```
this.$ajax.setLoading(true)
```

Comment: Thank you, I was also looking for this exact solution, although it looks pretty ugly...

Comment: Nah it make sense. We need a "reactive data holder" if our data is outside VueJs. Moreover VueJs instanciation is very light, so we can make as many VueJs instance as we want for this kind of usage.

Comment: Not bad, though [`Vue.observable`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable) is a cleaner way of doing this